# Bootstrap navbar links doesn't work on mobile

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this simple navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a id="header-logo" class="transition-100" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>main">YoutubeParty</a> 
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a id="header-add-button" class="button add-button header-button transition-100" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>main/add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a id="header-party-button" class="button party-button header-button transition-100" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>main/party"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"></span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a id="header-ranking-button" class="button ranking-button header-button transition-100" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>main/ranking"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

It works great on desktop but on mobile links are displayed below header.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPN0n.jpg)

And the buttons don't work. I can open links in the background, but when clicked, they don't direct to other pages.

---

EDIT: mobile source code

```
<!doctype html> 
  <html class="no-js" lang="pl"> 
  <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
    <title>YoutubeParty - najlepsze filmiki w sieci</title> 
    <meta name="description" content="Najlepsze filmy z youtube bez ruszania się z zakładki"> 
    <meta name="keywords" content="youtube, filmiki, śmieszne, ciekawe, party, humor, video, wideo" /> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700|Oswald&subset=latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://youtubeparty.pl/css/normalize.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://youtubeparty.pl/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://youtubeparty.pl/css/main.css"> 

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="http://youtubeparty.pl/js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation"> 
      <div class="container-fluid"> 
        <div class="navbar-header"> 
          <a id="header-logo" class="transition-100" href="http://youtubeparty.pl/main">YoutubeParty</a> 
        </div>
      <div class="navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
        <ul> 
          <li> 
            <a id="header-add-button" class="button add-button header-button transition-100" href="http://youtubeparty.pl/main/add">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </a> 
          </li> 
        <li> 
          <a id="header-party-button" class="button party-button header-button transition-100" href="http://youtubeparty.pl/main/party">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"></span>
          </a> 
        </li> 
        <li> 
          <a id="header-ranking-button" class="button ranking-button header-button transition-100" href="http://youtubeparty.pl/main/ranking">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
          </a> 
        </li> 
      </ul> 
    </div> 
  </div> 
</nav> 

<div id="add-container" class="container-fluid"> 
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-3">
    </div> 
  <div class="col-md-6 min480-container" style="text-align: center;"> 
    <h1 style="margin-bottom: 50px;">Dodaj filmik</h1> 

      <form action="http://youtubeparty.pl/main/addin" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="add_date" value="2014-08-30 10:34:27" /> 
        <label for="yt_link">Link:</label> 
        <input type="text" name="yt_link" value="" class="transition-100" id="yt_link" required="required" maxlength="1024" /> 
        <input type="submit" name="AddSubmit" value="Dodaj" class="button add-button transition-100" id="AddSubmit" /> 
      </form> 
    </div> 

    <div class="col-md-3">
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div> 
<div id="footer" class="container-fluid"> 
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div> 

    <div class="col-md-4"> 
      <div id="footer-container" class="min480-container"> 
        <p> Copyright © 2014 <a style="text-decoration: none" class="transition-100" href="http://youtubeparty.pl/">YoutubeParty.pl</a> 
        </p> 
        <ul> 
          <li>
            <a class="transition-100" href="http://youtubeparty.pl/main/contact">Kontakt</a>
          </li> 
          <li>
            <a class="transition-100" href="http://youtubeparty.pl/main/about">O stronie</a>
          </li> 
        </ul> 
      </div> 
    </div> 

    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div> 
<script> (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){ (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o), m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m) })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga'); ga('create', 'UA-54218399-1', 'auto'); ga('send', 'pageview'); function load() { gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', onYouTubeApiLoad); } function onYouTubeApiLoad() { gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyCa5mbsirih865iJOhykaWfrPKAhjssD9A'); } </script>
```

Comment: can you add browser source code for navbar

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the display problem but I had the same problem with links not opening the new pages on mobile. I managed to get past that by adding this:

```
div.dropdown-backdrop {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

I got there by reading this: [Bootstrap github issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9543).